# Does if / else do the same thing as ternary and logical && operator in React conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, logical-operators, conditional-operator, conditional-rendering

I have a React component which shows another component if `show` is `true`:

```
const ChildComponent = ({ show }: Props) => {
  if (show) {
    return <AnotherChild />;
  }
  return null;
};
```

Does above if/else do the same as a ternary operator or &&:

**Ternary:**

```
return show ? (
 <AnotherChild />;
) : null
```

**Logical && Operator:**

return (
{ show &&  }
);

Answer (score 0):

If `show` is always a boolean, then yes, those are all equivalent.

If `show` is falsey but not `null` nor `undefined`, there could be a bit of an issue, because it'd be rendered, for example:

```js
const App = ({ show }) => {
    return show && <div>content</div>;
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App show={0} />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Better to explicitly alternate with `null` with either the conditional operator or `if`/`else` than to use `&&`, if the type of the prop isn't constrained. (But it looks like you're using TypeScript, so the type *is* constrained, so it's all good)